# Need help with major category and permalink re-organization

Tags: categories, permalinks, redirect, 404-error

I would like to re-organize my categories and the permalink structure.

I want to rename and merge categories, make previous categories sub-categories and change the permalink structure from

`/%postname%/`

to

`/%category%/%postname%/`

The renaming and merging is not the problem, **I am rather concerned about the resulting 404 errors**.

How would you approach such a project?

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 1):

The canonical code within WordPress *should* actually already redirect those old posts to the new posts automatically. Have you tested that?

Comment: Well I tried it on a xampp test install with the same database... it didn't work.